# Effects and usage of intradermal injection

Tags: injections

I am studying about a technology that makes intradermal injection easier. I am lacking some background medical knowledge about this type of injection. I do have some basic knowledge of which skin layer intradermal injection is for, and some of the most used drugs (e.g. TB and allergy testing). However, I want to know some more details about how the injection works.

- what percentage of all the injections are given through intradermal route?
- what are the benefits and limitations of intradermal injection if any?
- I've learned most of the injections are subcutaneous. Why is that?
- What decides by which route the injection should be given?
- Is there any chance medications that were given subcutaneously be given through intradermal route? For example, could we give COVID 19 vaccine or insulin intradermally?

I am currently not working in medical field, instead, I'm in technology field, so I am not very familiar with medical concepts. Please bare with me if the questions were too obvious. I would really appreciate some detailed and clear answers for my confusions.
Thanks!

Comment: The custom on these sites is one question per question. You've asked five questions, each requiring a fairly long answer. Please consider editing it down to the aspect you most want to learn about, or it will likely be closed as needing more focus. Thanks. (As an aside, your paragraph/questions reveal a pattern that answers two of the questions. the question. What is particular about allergy testing and TB? A: they are given to elicit a *skin reaction*. Skin = epidermis + dermis.)